# I want to update the file (if necessary) and run the system command on current file

Tags: vim

I realize that I can `:nmap <leader>rc :!cat %<CR>` to provide an easy set of triggers, but I would like to do this instead.

`nmap <leader>rc :up :!cat %<CR>` but it complains about needing only one filename.  How do I get vim to recognize both commands, in series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `<CR>` after `:up`. `<CR>` tells vim you want a carriage return here.

```
nmap <leader>rc :up<CR> :!cat %<CR>
```

The reason up is complaining about multiple file names is that it sees `:!cat` and `%<CR>` as two arguments to up.

So the new macro executes

```
:up
:!cat %
```

instead of

```
:up :!cat %
```

(Side Note: you should probably use nnoremap instead of nmap)

---

ZyX recommends using the following mapping instead.

```
nnoremap ,rc :up\|execute "!cat" shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
```

This uses `|` to separate commands and escapes the `%`. Escaping the `%` leads to a more robust mapping just incase the filename contains special characters.

Help for [`:h execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#%3aexecute) and [`:h shellescape`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#shellescape%28%29)

Comment: I think I will double check this, as the fact that I did do a `nnoremap` was keeping my older version and that was complaining.  I think leads me to the answer.

Comment: It was indeed because of the nnoremap, continuing on the error before I added the carriage return.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: He should not also use `nnoremap`, but also forget about `%` in mappings: there is `:execute` and `shellescape(@%, 1)`. `%` is fine only if you are absolutely sure there are no special characters (e.g. space) both in the filename and in the directory path (depends on the current directory: `%` may or may not expand to the full path). As mappings are written far less times they are used it makes sense for them to be as much fail-proof as possible. I personally use mostly `%` when typing and only `shellescape()` (or even python `subprocess` via self-written framework) when creating mappings.

Comment: @ZyX Would you write up an answer?  And I did not think of :execute.  The bang isn't the same thing?  Of course, I can guarantee the no spaces in the directory or filename, as it is my system, but not needing to worry about it is better.

Comment: @vgoff `:execute` is a thing for constructing commands. You *still* use bang, but you wrap it into `:execute`: `nnoremap ,rc :up\|execute "!cat" shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>`. Note the different way to launch two commands sequentially: using `\|` is less verbose then `<CR>:`, but does not work always (some commands take bar as their argument).

Comment: @ZyX where the comma is actually leader, in your command structure, correct?

Comment: @vgoff I never use `<Leader>` for my own mappings, but most of time start mappings with comma. I am not setting `<Leader>` to comma because I do not want plugins possibly interfere with my own mappings.

Comment: OK, was confused, because the comma is used in vim.